# Viewport not working with redirect domain

Tags: php, css, .htaccess, laravel, viewport

I have a question I made a laravel website.

Problem is, the files, database etc are hosted at mpspoker.toedeloepoker.nl

But the domain name that is visited is mpspoker.nl.
We bought that domain and made it link to mpspoker.toedeloepoker.nl but when I visit it through mpspoker.nl

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

It's not working.

When I visit mpspoker.toedeloepoker.nl directly it is working.
[image: working]

And this one is the domain which people will be going to, and 
the viewport is not working.
[image: Not working]

Anybody knows how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it is not working is because the HTML document of `mpspoker.nl` does not have a a viewport meta tag and loads `mpspoker.toedeloepoker.nl` via a frameset.
You can solve this in two ways:

1. Replace the frameset on `mpspoker.nl` with a redirect. You can either use a meta refresh tag for this, or preferably a proper 301 redirect on the server side.
2. Add a viewport meta tag to the html document on `mpspoker.nl`